# Python - Passing urls vs. an HTTPResponse object

Tags: python, url, beautifulsoup

I have a list of URLs from which I want to scrape an attribute. Newbie to Python, so please excuse. Windows 7, 64-bit. Python 3.2.

The following code works. pblist is a list composed of dicts which include the key 'short_url'.

```
for j in pblist[0:10]:
    base_url = j['short_url']
    if hasattr(BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)), 'head') and \
        hasattr(BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)).head, 'title'):
            print("Has head, title attributes.")
            try:
                j['title'] = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)).head.title.string.encode('utf-8')
            except AttributeError:
                print("Encountered attribute error on page, ", base_url)
                j['title'] = "Attribute error."
                pass
```

The following code does not -- e.g., the code claims the BeautifulSoup object does not have head and title attributes.

```
for j in pblist[0:10]:
        base_url = j['short_url']
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)
        if hasattr(BeautifulSoup(page), 'head') and \
            hasattr(BeautifulSoup(page).head, 'title'):
                print("Has head, title attributes.")
                try:
                    j['title'] = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)).head.title.string.encode('utf-8')
                except AttributeError:
                    print("Encountered attribute error on page, ", base_url)
                    j['title'] = "Attribute error."
                    pass
```

Why? What's the difference between passing a url to urllib.request.urlopen within BeautifulSoup and passing the HTTPResponse ojbect that urllib.request.urlopen returns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The response provided by `urlopen()` is a file-like object, which means that it acts sort of like an iterator by default - namely, once you read through it once, you won't get any more data out of it (unless you explicitly reset it).

Thus, in the second version, the first invocation of `BeautifulSoup(page)` reads all of the data out of `page`, and subsequent invocations have no more data to read.

Instead, what you could do is this:

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)
page_content = page.read()
# ...
BeautifulSoup(page_content)
# ...
BeautifulSoup(page_content)
```

but even that is kind of inefficient. Instead, why not just make a BeautifulSoup object and pass that around?

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
# ...
# do something with soup
# ...
# do something with soup
```

---

Your code, modified to use a single soup object:

```
for j in pblist[0:10]:
        base_url = j['short_url']
        page = urllib.request.urlopen(base_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(page)
        if hasattr(soup, 'head') and \
            hasattr(soup.head, 'title'):
                print("Has head, title attributes.")
                try:
                    j['title'] = soup.head.title.string.encode('utf-8')
                except AttributeError:
                    print("Encountered attribute error on page, ", base_url)
                    j['title'] = "Attribute error."
                    pass
```